# info package osmar R

Tags: r, openstreetmap, osmar

I'm using `osmar` package with R but I would like to understand some outputs.
In general I would like to understand these outputs:

```
ua$nodes$attrs
ua$nodes$tags

ua$ways$attrs
ua$ways$tags
ua$ways$refs

ua$relations$attrs
ua$relations$tags
ua$relations$refs
```

in particular this one: `ua$nodes$attrs`

```
ua$nodes$attrs
            id visible           timestamp version changeset             user     uid      lat      lon
1   4610337290    true 2017-01-15 20:08:26       1  45198454 Michele Aquilani 3860151 41.87560 12.48151
2   1168031316    true 2015-01-27 12:21:52       3  28440993          Dinamik   39040 41.87572 12.48203
3    470954078    true 2009-08-19 11:42:50       1   2199720        GPS-Marco  110076 41.87548 12.48150
4    302148972    true 2010-10-07 14:57:51       2   5978872     dieterdreist   26139 41.87555 12.48166
...
```

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of these attributes are explained [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements#Common_attributes).

Let's take the first entry as an example: [node 4610337290](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/4610337290).

`id` is the unique identifier of this [element](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements). Each element (node, way, relation) in OSM has a unique ID, although these IDs are only unique *within* the element type. This means there can be a node having the same ID as a way or relation.

`visible` shows whether this node has already been deleted. Deleted nodes remain in the database, including their full history.

`timestamp` is the time of the last modification to this node.

`version` is the current version number of this node. Each modification leads to an increased version number.

`changeset` is the identifier of the last [changeset](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Changeset) that modified this element, in this case [changeset 45198454](https://www.openstreetmap.org/changeset/45198454). A changeset can contain modifications to more than one element.

`user` is the OSM user name of the user responsible for the last `changeset` to this node.

`uid` is the unique identifier of the `user`.

`lat` and `lon` are the latitude and longitude of the node.

Answer (score 0):

simple version:

it's the attributes of those who contributed to that project.

```
?osmar
```

yields:

```
nodes
     A list with two data frames containing the attributes and tags of the nodes.
```

basically the who/when/where on the edits made to the object.

for more, see the [detailed documentation here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/eugster-schlesinger.pdf).